# CakePHP FormHelper for uploading an image file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have included image formhelper for uploading an image file, Where i am getting only 'name' attribute but not 'tmp_name', 'size', 'type', 'error' attributes..
Please give me the solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `form` allows uploads:

`<?php echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('type'=>'file')); ?>`

adds an `enctype` of `"multipart/form-data"`, allowing file uploads.

Answer (score 2):

To add a file upload field to a form, you must first make sure that the form enctype is set to "multipart/form-data", so start off with a create function such as the following.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Document', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data') );
// OR
echo $this->Form->create('Document', array('type' => 'file'));
```

read more http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1411/File-Fields